# Retrieving data from ArrayList which contains database rows

Tags: java, database, arraylist

I have retrived some datas from DB and I have stored it in an `ArrayList`.  The `ArrayList` contains some 50 rows returned each row containin 4 columns.  How do I access a particular column of a particular object in `ArrayList`?  Can someone help me with this?

Comment: When you say ArrayList, did you mean ResultSet? ArrayList does not have columns. Or do they?

Comment: No they don't. They are the same thing as Vectors sans thread safety.

Comment: The result ArrayList contains String arrays which has the mappings for each column for the resultset.

Comment: so, why don't you do `myArrayList.get(indexOfTheRow)[indexOfTheColumn]`

Comment: I dono how to access the index of the column.. :( !!

Comment: The best option for you is to create a list Java objects which represents your row. Pull columns from `ResultSet` using `resultSet.getString(columnName)` and store the result in the object. Do the same for each row, and create a List of objects. Then use the list of object to do your work. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @user533329: Well whose code builds the arrays to start with? If it's you, then *you* should know which column has which index. If it's someone else's code, see what they can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the exact issue here. List is based on the index and hence you can access any data based on index. Another option is to convert use Map which allows you to refer to the data based on a key you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Due to new data posted in comments on the question, this is now know to not be what OP wants. I'd delete it but, given what I've read from him/her so far, I'm afraid he/she may be forever flummoxed by the disappearance of an answer.

ORIGINAL ANSWER

If you really have an `ArrayList` and not a `ResultSet` then do this

```
myList.get( desiredRow*column_width /*4*/ + desiredCol);
```

This assumes row-major ordering.

Comment: sorry, can u please be brief on your answer

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is brief -.-